# How to turn access token from public access type application to rpt token in keycloak

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm using a Single Page React js application to log in via Keycloak login page. If I send this access token to my API which is confidential client, I can not obtain a RPT token with this access token.

Is there any way to extract authorization permissions out of this access token?

I tried to execute RPT call with my access token at backend side but token validation failed. Another application with a direct grant worked out perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Storing an access token in a SPA application is a bad idea, the access token should be stored on the server side.

When you want to access a protected api, this api should be called by another server (not a client application), the idea is to keep the access token safe on the server so that a attacker can't easily obtain this access token to perform calls on behalf of the your user.

OAUTH is a protocol about authentication, authorization is not handled by OAUTH, for simple application is probably best to handle the authorization within the application.

https://jwt.io/ is a easy tool to decode your access tokens